# Break a long regular expression into several lines in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, word-wrap

I want to break the following regular expression into several lines of code.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Aarau|Aargau| <break here> more|words|follow|here/g, function(m) {
  return '<span style="background-color:lightblue">'+m+'</span>';
});
```

Comment: Where is the replacement string? Post an example along with expected output.

Comment: The output is not important. I just want to wrap the line in my editor!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5pha5tzc/

Comment: have you tried `"first part of regex" + "second part of regex"` and break line after the `+` sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easy way to break the line:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    /Aarau|Aargau|more|words|follow|here/g,
    function (m) {
      return '<span style="background-color:lightblue">'+m+'</span>';
    }
);
```

If you have a really long regular expression, write it as a string and compile it:

```
var longRegex = new RegExp('Aarau|Aargau|aardvark|aardwolf|' +
    'aargh|more|stuff|earth|worm|earthworm|geese|moose|mice|' +
    'yet|more|and|more|et|cetera|and|so|on', 'g');

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(longRegex,
    function (m) {
      return '<span style="background-color:lightblue">'+m+'</span>';
    }
);
```

One more possibility is to write the individual words in an array, then join them with `|` when you compile the regular expression. This is especially convenient if you're already storing a word array.

```js
var words = ['Aarau', 'Aargau', 'aardvark', 'aardwolf', 'aargh',
    'more', 'stuff', 'earth', 'worm', 'earthworm', 'geese', 'moose', 'mice',
    'yet', 'more', 'and', 'more', 'et', 'cetera', 'and', 'so', 'on'];

var wordRegex = new RegExp(words.join('|'), 'g');
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(wordRegex,
    function (m) {
      return '<span style="background-color:lightblue">'+m+'</span>';
    }
);
```

```html
There is an aardwolf eating earth containing worms in Aargau.
```

Comment: But what if I had the code Aarau|Aargau|more|words|follow|here|Aarau|Aargau|more|words|follow|here|Aarau|Aargau|more|words|follow|here|Aarau|Aargau|more|words|follow|here ?

Comment: See the alternative: compiling a regular expression from a string. I've just revised my answer.

Comment: Because you misspelled `RegExp`. The `p` is missing.

Comment: Also, the `new` keyword is recommended. So you want to write `new RegExp(...)`.

Comment: I was used to the word RegEx :)

Comment: Yes, we've all been there. It's confusing.